# Selenium Page Object Model: Best way to handle Return Pages for Modals

Tags: c#, selenium, pageobjects

I'm currently working on the POM of a web app, that allows to open modals from the navigation bar. The navigation bar stays the same for every page you're on. Each modal can be opened from every page.
I have defined a page object for each modal. Also the navigation bar is a pageobject,
What would be the best way to return to the page, that the modal was opened from?

So for example, you are on the Page FooPage and open modal AboutModal. What is the best way to return to FooPage? It should also work for BarPage and other Pages.

My first approach was, that i define a BasePage Object, which only includes the webdriver and navigationbar. i extend every Page on the web app from this BasePage. Then i could do something like this:

Code for FooPage:

```
    public class FooPage: BasePage
    {
        private NavigationBar NavBar;

        public FooPage(IWebDriver driver): base(driver)
        {
            ...
            this.NavBar = new NavigationBar(driver);
        }
        public NavigationBar Navigate()
        {
            return NavBar;
        }
        ...
    }
```

```
 public class NavigationBar
    {
        ...
        public openAboutModal(BasePage currentPage)
        {
            log.Info("Open About Modal");
            Action.Click(NavigationBarElements.AboutButton);
            return new AboutModal(Driver, currentPage);
        }
    }
```

```
    public class AboutModal
    {
        ...
        protected BasePage ReturnPage; 
        public AboutModal(IWebDriver driver, BasePage returnPage)
        {
            ...
            this.ReturnPage = returnPage;
        }

        public BasePage CloseAboutModal()
        {
            return this.ReturnPage;
        }
        ...
    }
```

This is not practical and not intuitive, because we have to remember on which pageobject we currently are, when writing tests. Also only the methods from BasePage are available, which means we have to additionaly navigate back to the page we wanted to be on.
So instead of writing

```
    public class ModalTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void CheckAboutModal()
        {
            Login() // FooPage
                .Navigate() //NavigationBar
                .openAboutModal() // AboutModal
                .doSomeStuff() //AboutModal
                .CloseAboutModal(); //FooPage
        }
    }
```

we have to do

```
        public void CheckAboutModal()
        {
            Login() // FooPage
                .Navigate() //NavigationBar
                .openAboutModal(new FooPage(Driver)) // AboutModal
                .doSomeStuff() // AboutModal
                .CloseAboutModal() // BasePage
                .Navigate() //NavigationBar
                .ToFooPage(); // FooPage 
        }
    }
```

How can I return to the calling Page of the modal, without making Testwriting to complicated?

Comment: chances are you don't have to.  The modal is part of the page you are on.  (You're still on the same "page"... this is usually JS changing a style or appending to the current DOM)  If the modal was in another tab/window, you'd have to switch the driver to it to get it's contents.  If the modals are all the same and are all triggered from the navigation bar, you might consider just making them a part of the navigation class.  (don't take the "Page" in POM too literally... think of it as just "re-usable properties and methods")

Comment: i already divide the "Pages" in reusable components/Page fragments. Putting modals in the navigationbar class feels wrong, because it doesn't simulate the behaviour correctly. You still dont "return" to the previous state, instead you have to use the navigation bar to return to the page you originally were on (and maybe lose unsaved changes on the page). But your approach is better than mine, so i think i will use it, even if it does not feel right. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than write your test as one giant method-chaining call, use variables whenever you need to refer back to a certain page model. Your test can simply become:

```
var foo = Login();

foo.Navigate()
   .openAboutModal()
       .doSomeStuff()
       .CloseAboutModal();

// Continue your test after closing the modal
foo.SomeOtherOperation();
```

In cases like this, the modal doesn't need to return anything. The `CloseAboutModal()` method can be a `void` return type. Your test should understand the larger context in which the modal is being used, and create local variables appropriately in order to "return" back to the main page.